# An object reference is required for the non-static field, how do i solve this?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I made a wpf appliction and I just simply generated everything with Ado.Net entity Data Model  from my existing SQL server database.

I am trying to fill my datagrid but it keeps saying this error:

> An Object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property'PhishFinderDBentitites.PhishingUrls'

This is my method for filling my datagrid code in my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            ObjectQuery<DataAccess.PhishingUrl> PhishingUrls = PhishFinderDBEntities.PhishingUrls;

            var query =
            from PhishingUrl in PhishingUrls
            orderby PhishingUrl.score
            select new { PhishingUrl.score, PhishingUrl.Path };
            URLGRID.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
}
```

What should i change?

Comment: PhishFinderDBEntities entities = new PhishFinderDBEntities();

Comment: @Gusman    PhishFinderDBEntities entities = new PhishFinderDBEntities();
                ObjectQuery<DataAccess.PhishingUrl> PhishingUrls = PhishFinderDBEntities.PhishingUrls; i did that did not help

Comment: @Gusman Maybe i am putting it on the wrong place? Where should i put it?

Comment: show us how did you initialize/create this object `PhishFinderDBEntities`

Comment: @Waqar Ahmed,  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
PhishFinderDBEntities entities = new PhishFinderDBEntities();
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not created an instance of the entities, you neet to instantiate it and use the collections in it:

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    {
        var entities = new PhishFinderDBEntities();
        var PhishingUrls = entities.PhishingUrls;

        var query =
        from PhishingUrl in PhishingUrls
        orderby PhishingUrl.score
        select new { PhishingUrl.score, PhishingUrl.Path };
        URLGRID.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
    }
}
```